# Not able to send local file using axios in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, httprequest

I would like to send a file to [PowerBI Import API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/imports/postimportingroup#importinfo)

I'm successfully doing it in Postman , so I exported code to axios using postman interface.

Here's what I get

```
var data = new FormData();
data.append('', fs.createReadStream('/Users/hh/Downloads/MAuto.pbix'));

var config = {
    method: 'post',
    url: 'https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/cd936ccf-03ae-4df4-8e76-xxx/imports?datasetDisplayName=autotest',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${tokenResponse.accessToken}`,
        ...data.getHeaders()
    },
    data: data
};

axios(config)
    .then(function (response) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

The API rise a `400 Error` with this message `InvalidFileSizeError`

I don't think that's MS API issue because I have already done it using Postman.

Comment: Is there a content-length header in `...data.getHeaders()`, and does it match up with the actual size?

Comment: I've checked, no `content-length` in headers , how can I set it ? in `data` I have a property `maxDataSize` is it the `content-length`?

Comment: `maxDataSize` is something specific to that library I believe. If there's no `content-length` then it wouldn't be a mismatch between the content-length and the actual request size minus headers, so that's probably not the issue.  Have you tried with a different request library like `node-fetch` or `request`? I'm just throwing out troubleshooting ideas, no idea if that would actually fix things.